# Can I make a parameter of a method null by default?

Tags: java

I want to manage my exceptions like this :

```java
protected String displayException(Exception e, String specificMessage) {
        String message = (specificMessage == null) ? e.getMessage() : specificString;
        return message;
    }
```

Do I have an annotation that would allow me to do so (example @Nullable or @Optional)? And if yes, in which library can I find it (example @Nullable is in the Spring library and in the Jetbrains library)

Comment: In Java single way is using method overloading. protected String displayException(String specificMessage){displayException(null,specificMessage);}

Answer (score 1):

You can overload your method:

```
protected String displayException(Exception e) {
    return displayException(e, null)
}
```

Comment: Yes it's my second option I was just wondering if java 8 had an annotation for this kind of problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeGaujac No there isn't. And I think there is no need for it.